# How do I keep my database file inside my JAR?

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jar

When I run my JAR, it creates a SQLite database file in the same directory it is in so I need to keep them together to maintain consistency. Is there a way to have the database file created and accessed inside the JAR so I only need to worry about the JAR itself?

Comment: In a word, no.  You can't dynamically modify a JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently sqlite-jdbc can open resources on it's own. Per this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/xerial/Oayzj5nrJGk, add :resource to the path. So try the following:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::resource:package/test.sqlite");
```

Replacing package with the '/' separated path to the package this file is in.

Be aware that it will actually copy the file to a tmp directory.